# Building a simple generative adversarial net with neuralnet in R

Tags: r, neural-network

I am trying to reproduce the example given in [Goodfellow, I. et al.: Generative Adversarial Nets](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2661v1.pdf)

The pseudocode is given on page 4 as "Algorithm 1". I am trying to rebuild it with the neuralnet package in R:

```
library(neuralnet)

train_iter <- 10
steps <- 1
m <- 100

# initialize D and G
z <- sort(runif(m))
x <- sort(rnorm(m))
data <- cbind(z, x)
D <- neuralnet( , data = data, hidden = 11) # unclear how to define formula
G <- neuralnet(x ~ z, data = data, hidden = 11)

for (i in 1:train_iter) {
  for (k in 1:steps) {
    z <- sort(runif(m))
    x <- sort(rnorm(m))
    data <- cbind(z, x)
    err_fct_d <- function(x, z) {
      -log(compute(D, x)$net.result + log(1 - compute(D, compute(G, z)$net.result)$net.result))
    }
    D <- neuralnet( , data = data, hidden = 11, err.fct = err_fct_d, startweights = D$weights) # unclear how to define formula
  }
  z <- sort(runif(m))
  data <- cbind(z, x)
  err_fct_g <- function(x, z) {
    log(1 - compute(D, compute(G, z)$net.result)$net.result)
  }
  G <- neuralnet(x ~ z, data = data, hidden = 11, err.fct = err_fct_g, startweights = G$weights)
}
```

**My questions**
My first question is whether it is possible to use the neuralnet package with these customized error functions in the above way at all.
 My second question concerns the discriminator network: I don't know how to train it, i.e. how to define the formula part of the neuralnet function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this does not work out of the box because `err.fct` has to be an analytically differentiable function and the `compute` function prevents this.

**Edit**: I contacted the author of the package and he wrote:

> I checked your GAN example and I think that is not possible with neuralnet because the way error functions are handled is not flexible enough. [...]